# Fragment Maintain View State on detach/destroy/orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-view

I have an application that has two fragments as actionbar tabs.  The fragments are attached/detached when switching between the tabs.  Any time I switch a tab, change the orientation, or press back to exit the application, the view is destroyed.  I need it to be restored to its previous state when it is reopened.  I know, at least on the orientation change, to use onSaveInstanceState and save the data there so I can restore it when the view is recreated.  However, for some reason even though the data gets saved properly to the outState bundle and is read properly from the savedInstanceState bundle, the view doesn't update to what it should update to.  For example, I start a service and while that service is running I need to hide two buttons and show two other buttons in their place.  I use a boolean to check if the service is running, then put it in the outState so I can see which buttons to show or hide.  My code for that is:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("isRunning", isRunning);
}
```

In onCreateView:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        isRunning = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isRunning", false);
        if (isRunning) {
            showStopButton();
        }
}
```

And the showStopButton code is:

```
private void showStopButton() {
    btnStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnReset.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnLoop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

So all this works, the boolean is found as true while the service is running, and showStopButton() is called.  However, it doesn't appear to actually do anything.  The view state just resets itself to as if the first two buttons (which I want to be hidden) are shown instead of the ones I actually want to be shown.  Any idea why this is happening/how to fix it?

I also have a listview that I need to stay populated with the same values as before that I can't get to work either.

Also, onSaveInstanceState isn't called when switching tabs (and I think not when pressing the back button either?).  How should I go about retaining the view state in these cases?

Comment: Are you sure that showButton() is running? I ask because it shouldn't since when you save it, you stage the boolean as "stopwatchRunning", and when you restore you're looking for "isRunning", which will default to false since it's named differently.

Comment: Oh whoops, that was old code.  I changed it so that they're the same variable.  showStopButton() is definitely being called.  It goes through it and sets the visibility of everything, but for some reason it doesn't actually show properly in the app.

Comment: Try triggering that from `onStart()`. Or set `setRetainInstance(true)`

Comment: I fixed the problem with the buttons.  Apparently I had to call showStopButton() from outside the savedInstanceState check?  I don't understand why I would need to do that, but it works now.  I'm having trouble with the listview though.